# D'Alembertian and index notation

Tags: general-relativity, notation

Is $$\partial_{\alpha}\partial^{\alpha}\phi $$ the same as $$\partial^{\alpha}\partial_{\alpha}\phi $$ ?

Could you explain why, please?

Comment: So far 4 people bothered to downvote the question without commenting on why. I don't care why, just finding it fascinating what a helpful bunch people here are.

Comment: I'd wager the downvotes are because this is a rather straight-forward computation, so why waste time giving a reason (or an answer) when you've appeared to put little effort yourself.

Answer (score 1):

No they are not the same.

$$ \partial^\alpha\partial_\alpha \phi = g^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\beta\partial_\alpha \phi $$

while

$$ \partial_\alpha\partial^\alpha \phi = \partial_\alpha g^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\beta \phi =  g^{\alpha\beta} \partial_\alpha\partial_\beta \phi +(\partial_\alpha g^{\alpha\beta})(\partial_\beta \phi) $$.

Hence if $\phi$ is sufficiently smooth to exchange the order of partial derivatives

$$ \partial_\alpha\partial^\alpha \phi - \partial^\alpha\partial_\alpha \phi = (\partial_\alpha g^{\alpha\beta})(\partial_\beta \phi)$$.

So unless $\partial_\alpha g^{\alpha\beta} = 0$ (which is true for example in Minkowski space). The two are not equal.